# How i can make static navigation icon?

Tags: android, android-navigation

I had used navigation slider menu code from here -> [Android Sliding Menu using Navigation Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)
But when ever i click on sliding menu navigation icon that goes little inside and change the position. I need is that it be constant there should be no movement on Click it on the time the navigation list is open.

Comment: I guess it will not be possible in this example because navigation drawer is opening and closing 
for static icon you have to make your drawer static

Comment: This is possible, but it's altering the standard UI design, which is generally discouraged. Do you really want to do that?

Comment: @hulk saviour thnxs!I'm have already used static drawer,could you suggest me any other way to do this.

Comment: @HiteshMatnani  I can give you the idea but first of all tell me ,do you want to close your drawer  or not?
If no then you have to divide your screen in two parts and you have to use left side fragment for the list of menu and right side for the replacement of fragment with the frame layout

Comment: @hulk saviour i can close the drawer if there is need in your concept other it will be fine.

Comment: @ Mike MYes i will do that but how i fix it please guide me in details thnxs!

Comment: @HiteshMatnani and on the click of the action bar icon you can hide the static list menu ,in this way you can use action bar icon without changing it's postion,navigation drawer kind of a functionality as well you can hide and show it as well

Comment: @HiteshMatnani ican give you the code to hide fragment because rest of the code is lengthy

Comment: @hulksaviour yha please give me that code! it will help me a lot thnxs!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62226/discussion-between-hulk-saviour-and-hitesh-matnani).

Comment: @HiteshMatnani Are you talking about the 3-line icon? You want to keep it from moving when opening/closing the drawer?

Comment: @MikeM. yes i need that to be static it. could you help me please to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ActionBarDrawerToggle` is what causes that behavior. It does this in methods it implements as a `DrawerLayout.DrawerListener`, which we can override, and not call up to the `super` methods.

For the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` class found in the `support-v4` library, we need only override one method:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(...) {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        // Do not call super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        ...
    }
};
```

With the class from `appcompat-v7`, we need to override two additional methods:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(...) {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset){
        // Do not call super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
        // Do not call super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
        // Do not call super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: What i have to do in // Do nothing

Comment: Nothing. This method is overriding the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` method that's moving the icon. Don't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement this is the code to hide fragment,Here lvf is the name assigned to the fragment.

```
lvf = new ListViewFragment();
```

Here is the list view sample code

```
list2.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

                FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out);

                if (lvf.isHidden()) {
                    ft.show(lvf);
                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                } else {
                    ft.hide(lvf);

                    layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                ft.commit();



        }
    });
```